# Find the size of an array of hash in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

How do you get the size of the following array of hashes?

I thought this would do it, but it did not work...

```
print Dumper scalar $item->{'detail'};
$VAR1 = [
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'entree',  'url_name' => 'entree' },
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'dessert', 'url_name' => 'desert' },
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'drink',   'url_name' => 'drink'  }
];
```

Or how can I print all the `url_name` (entree, desert, drink) in the array of hashes without knowing the size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an array reference. To get the size of the referenced array, first dereference the reference:

```
print scalar @{$item->{'detail'}};
```

And to list the URLs:

```
my $v = [
      { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'entree', 'url_name' => 'entree' },
      { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'dessert', 'url_name' => 'desert' },
      { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'drink', 'url_name' => 'drink' }
];   # or $v = $item->{'detail'};

foreach my $h (@$v) {
  print $h->{url_name}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think you need the array size in order to print the url_name values. Nonetheless, here's how it works.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $v = [   # note that this is a scalar value
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'entree', 'url_name' => 'entree' },
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'dessert', 'url_name' => 'desert' }, 
    { 'content' => undef, 'name' => 'drink', 'url_name' => 'drink' } 
];  
my $item = { detail => $v };        # recreate your structure $item->{detail}
my $size = @$v;                     # this is how its done with $v
my $size2 = @{ $item->{detail} };   # and with your original structure
my @x = map $_->{url_name}, @$v;    # extract url_name values
print Dumper \@x;
```

As you see, `$item->{detail}` and `$v` are identical. When you feed this scalar value directly (through the `scalar` function, which does nothing in this case) to Dumper, you get the printed value seen in `$v` above. All that `scalar` does is change the context used with `print` and enforce a scalar context rather than list context. We can do the same thing by using scalar assignment (`$size` and `$size2`).

When using the original structure, you need to use the `@{ }` brackets to clarify for perl that what is inside them is an array ref.

As you see, extracting the values is easily done with a `map` statement. It acts as a loop, iterating over all the values in `@$v` (or `@{ $item->{detail} }`), returning for each value the statement `$_->{url_name}`.